# Is there any library other than gphoto2 to use remote capture in Canon G10?

Tags: canon, software, tethering, software-recommendation, framerate

I am using gphoto2 library to remote capture on my Canon G10.It does not take photos at the required frame rate.Currently i have not been able to achieve  fastest the camera can achieve which is 1.4fps.Is there any library or sdk other than gphoto2 which can click faster photos with Canon G10. Also if some changes can be made in gphoto2 to make it faster suggest them too.

Comment: I wonder if you would get a better response by posting this question in software?

Comment: Are you asking for faster shutter speed, less shutter lag or higher frame rate? What are you current results? Regarding frame rate, continuous shooting  with G10 is limited at [0.6 fps with continuous AF and RAW, 1.4fps without](http://www.dcresource.com/reviews/canon/powershot_g10-review/); no software would speed up past that.

Comment: Also it might be worth checking out the Magic Lantern software and/or the Canon Developers APi

Comment: @Imre i have to achieve higher frame rate. I have not achieved frame rate of 1.4 fps

Answer (score 1):

In some regions, Canon has included RemoteCapture DC software with the G10. On Windows, there's [PSRemote](http://www.breezesys.com/PSRemote/index.htm).

I have no direct experience with gphoto2, but its idea seems to be quite simple, translating requested commands to camera-specific datagrams and as such the library itself is unlikely to be a major cause for slowness.

Rather, the [G10 firmware seems to do full on-and-off cycle](https://www.flickr.com/groups/915624@N22/discuss/72157623276692529/72157625607258393) for each capture requested by computer, and this of course is much slower than shooting images manually. Perhaps [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/G10) would act more sensibly.

The easiest way to increase frame rate would be to capture video instead of still photos, and extract frames from that.

For still images, other than getting a faster camera, frame rate can be maximized by trying to spend less time for each shot, such as

- use lower resolution (JPEG, no RAW) to deal with less data;
- use manual exposure so there would be no need to measure light;
- use manual focus so there would be no need to focus;
- switch off instant viewing of captured photo;
- avoid using flash so its capacitors would not need refilling;
- use higher ISO or more light so you could use a faster shutter speed;
- use continuous shooting mode so the camera can optimize to deliver many shots quickly;
- leaving data in camera is likely faster than tethering, tethering via cable is likely faster than over Wi-Fi.